# angularjs : @mention in textarea

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to display an autocomplete form triggered by the word `@` in my textarea like this library http://ichord.github.io/At.js/ but only using angularjs & css

What kind of directive should I write ? Also, is there a way to implement this with the angular bootstrap UI typehead directive ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See https://github.com/jeff-collins/ment.io for a directive that likely does what you are looking for.

Comment: @BobbyShark I've used that. adds popup templates to document in the number of textarea (input)s in page, In my case, more than 100 on  a single page. And also menus remain in page even when route changes! not a good idea.

Comment: @alihaghighatkhah Thank you I'll give it a try. I used ment.io so far and had to tweak it a bit for my needs. I'll give you feedback on your project

Comment: @BobbyShark Thanks bobby, I'll wait for that

Answer (score 4):

I've written [angular-otobox](https://github.com/alihaghighatkhah/angular-otobox), a dependency-less angular directive for mentioning, tagging and higlighiting words in text, it's easy to use. have look, it's easy to use.

Comment: wellcome, feel free to ask if any problems

Comment: @alihaghighatkhah I'm trying to use your project but I can't get it work.. Have you an example page to see how to setup it correctly? I used `<script src="../../js/otobox.js"></script><script src="../../js/angular-otobox.js"></script>` along with the css and added `angular-otobox` in the angular module config

Comment: @BobbyShark plus these, you need to add angular-otobox to dependencies of your app, also otoboxConfig directive containing settings of your activator(s).Try like these and I'll try creating a codepen ASAP

Comment: @alihaghighatkhah Yes that's what I've done. I haven't used config directives, only `<textarea otobox="mention.array"> etc...` But can't get it work.. Also does the otobox-source allow to use array ?

Comment: @BobbyShark I made a codepen: http://codepen.io/alihaghighatkhah/pen/ZYmKvQ. hope it helps

Comment: @alihaghighatkhah thank you but this isn't working at all. `Error: otobox - Name, key and source fields are mandatory for activator object.` Plus the lack of documentation, I will keep with ment.io

Comment: @BobbyShark It's a little wired, cause I checked and it works in all browsers, no errors. Let me know if I could be of any assistance.

Comment: @alihaghighatkhah I tested on Firefox ubuntu version. Will test on a proper new project on win7 and give u feedback tomorrow ok. Thanks for your help

Comment: @alihaghighatkhah -- Lack of example code makes this pretty tough to understand, fyi. Perhaps create a (working) Plunkr? The codepen doesn't run in Chrome.

Comment: @alihaghighatkhah a demo would be nice

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a script for my needs (not AngularJS), but also might help achieving what you are looking for.

[image]

HTML:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="input-box" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <div id="mention-select-choices" class="hidden"></div>
</div>
```

To see the JS part, got to JSFiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/hsjqzkt3/6/

The script supports predefined list of names, auto-completion, custom style, special characters and many more.

Also, possible to be easily converted to AngularJS if needed.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJs is quite outdated. please refer below dependencies for Angular 2+ versions:

- [angular-mentions](https://github.com/dmacfarlane/angular-mentions)
- [ngx-mention](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@netcreaties/ngx-mention)