# angularjs tagging functionality with @ symbol in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am creating a app where users can comment on something. So to type the comment I have provided a textarea. Now I want to provide users with tagging functionality. By tagging I mean than when `@` is typed in the textarea automatically a list of all the users be shown than the commenter can choose a user and that username will appear as @username. Characters after the `@` symbol should work as typeahead. For ex: If I type @ma than only those users whose usernames starts with `ma` must be shown. I have a backend API for this. The API will return the results based on the typed characters.

How can I accomplish this in front-end ?

```
I am using angular js version 1.4.7
bootstrap 3.3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries available for same. Some of them are as below.

https://github.com/jeff-collins/ment.io

https://github.com/alihaghighatkhah/angular-otobox

The details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326149/angularjs-mention-in-textarea)